# VB Recursive Lambda Sub does not compile

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I've created the following recursive lambda expression that will not compile, giving the error

Type of 'OpenGlobal' cannot be inferred from an expression containing 'OpenGlobal'.

```
            Dim OpenGlobal = Sub(Catalog As String, Name As String)
                             If _GlobalComponents.Item(Catalog, Name) Is Nothing Then
                                 Dim G As New GlobalComponent
                                 G.Open(Catalog, Name)
                                 _GlobalComponents.Add(G)
                                 For Each gcp As GlobalComponentPart In G.Parts
                                     OpenGlobal(gcp.Catalog, gcp.GlobalComponentName)
                                 Next
                             End If
                         End Sub
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is type inference.  It can't figure out the type for your OpenGlobal variable because it depends on itself.  If you set an explicit type, you might be okay:

```
 Dim OpenGlobal As Action(Of String, String) = '...
```

This simple test program works as expected:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim OpenGlobal As Action(Of Integer) = Sub(Remaining As Integer)
                                               If Remaining > 0 Then
                                                   Console.WriteLine(Remaining)
                                                   OpenGlobal(Remaining - 1)
                                               End If
                                           End Sub

    OpenGlobal(10)
    Console.WriteLine("Finished")
    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub
```